# Vue custom module resolution doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem. The answer here is below

**Question**

I create a new `vue` project via `vue/cli`: `vue create hello-world` (all the  options he asks are selected).

Then I create a `index.ts` file in `hello-world/libs/test-lib` folder with the following content:

```
export const item = 1;
```

In `main.ts` and `home.vue` I imported this module to use them:

```
import {item} from '@libs/test-lib';

console.log('item', item);
```

and in my `tsconfig.json` I add:

```
 "@libs/*": [
   "libs/*"
  ]
```

My `vscode` is resolve this path. but when I try to run `build` or `serve` (`npm run build`) As a result, I am getting an error:

> @libs/test-lib in ./src/main.ts,
>   ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save @libs/test-lib

I think I did everything according by the [module-resolution guide from webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

[image]

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found it!**

Because I use `babel` with `typescript` (from the configuration of vue/cli), then I need to use [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

So to solve the problem, I created `babel` config file `.babelrc`, (in the root) with the following content:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "@libs": "./libs"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I ran the command again, **And it worked!**